# PhoneNumberUtils.compare() is not giving right result

Tags: android, android-cursor

I am making an SMS Application and using `PhoneNumberUtils.compare()` to correctly handle phone number formats.

```
public void GetMessages(String PhoneNumber)
{
    Uri message = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
    ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
    Cursor c = cr.query(message, null, null, null, null);
    if (c.getCount() > 0)
    {
        while (c.moveToNext())
        {
            String ContactNumber = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address"));
            if(PhoneNumberUtils.compare(ContactNumber, PhoneNumber))
            {
                //Match
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above code works fine and I am getting Messages for a particular Phone Number. However, at another place (retrieving messages from my own database) `compare()` function is giving weird results. Following is the code.

```
public void GetMessages(String Number)
{
    String Query = "Select * FROM PhoneNumber";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(Query, null);
    if (c.getCount() > 0)
    {
        while (c.moveToNext())
        {
            String DBNumber = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("PhoneNumber"));
            if (PhoneNumberUtils.compare(Number, DBNumber));
            {
                //Match - Breakpoint set here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I get at the breakpoint

[image: DBNumber and Number are different but compare() gives true]

`DBNumber` and `Number` are different but `compare()` gives true. Please Help!

This is the part of my logcat as asked:

```
D/~~~﹕ DBNumber=0333357xxxx;PhoneNumber=+92332465xxxx;match=‌​false
D/~~~﹕ DBNumber=0333357xxxx;PhoneNumber=+92332465xxxx;match=‌​false
D/~~~﹕ DBNumber=0333357xxxx;PhoneNumber=+92332465xxxx;match=‌​false
D/~~~﹕ DBNumber=0333357xxxx;PhoneNumber=+92332465xxxx;match=‌​false
D/~~~﹕ DBNumber=0333357xxxx;PhoneNumber=+92332465xxxx;match=‌​false
D/~~~﹕ DBNumber=0333357xxxx;PhoneNumber=+92332465xxxx;match=‌​false
D/~~~﹕ DBNumber=0333357xxxx;PhoneNumber=+92332465xxxx;match=‌​false
D/~~~﹕ DBNumber=0333357xxxx;PhoneNumber=+92332465xxxx;match=‌​false
D/~~~﹕ DBNumber=0333357xxxx;PhoneNumber=+92332465xxxx;match=‌​false
D/~~~﹕ DBNumber=0333357xxxx;PhoneNumber=+92332465xxxx;match=‌​false
D/~~~﹕ DBNumber=0333357xxxx;PhoneNumber=+92332465xxxx;match=‌​false
```

Comment: I guess, the correct number is inside the table, right? You are using a cursor which goes through  the hole table. Can You show, how exactly You are getting the boolean value (that´s not included in Your code...)?

Comment: Yes offcourse! The correct Number is in the second row but it shows match in the first row which is different number.

Comment: What do you mean by getting boolean value? compare() function actually returns a boolean. In if condition I have to save the values of other columns in the table if the number matches. I think it is irrelevant.

Comment: maybe just a copy paste  issue, but You wrote: if (PhoneNumberUtils.compare(Number, DBNumber)); . Your if statement is out of the brackets...delete the semikolon....

Comment: No I mean, why You are sure You get the true value, do You just make a Log?

Comment: No! The code in if condition (where I have set the breakpoint) is being executed. I set a breakpoint to further check the values of both parameters ("Number" and "DBNumber") which are shown in the picture. They are totally different so compare() should return false for this row.

Comment: Please add `Log.d("~~~","ContactNumber="+ContactNumber+";PhoneNumber="+PhoneNumber+";match="+PhoneNumberUtils.compare(ContactNumber, PhoneNumber));` before the `if` statement and post the output shown by `adb logcat | grep '~~~'`

Comment: I have posted the output as you asked. It looks like compare() is giving false but I wonder why it goes in if condition.